# How to root Samsung Galaxy Discover?

Tags: rooting

I just bought a Galaxy Discover. I can't figure out how to root it.

All I could find was this [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460) link; but, I get an error running `mount`, so the root doesn't complete successfully.

How can I root my Discover?

Comment: There also isn't any ClockWordMod for it. Gah.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to root my Samsung Galaxy Discover using [UnlockRoot](http://www.unlockroot.com/download.html).

Basically all you need to do is download [this installer](http://downloadcdn.betterinstaller.com/installers/9/9/UnlockRoot_downloader_by_UnlockRoot.exe) from their website and run it. **However,** the installer will attempt to dump a bunch of junk on your computer, so you need to be very careful. Read each page of the wizard to make sure the appropriate options are selected.

Once installed, connect your phone via USB and make sure USB debugging is enabled. Start the application and click the big green "root" button. You should receive a popup containing a button with the name of your phone. Simply click the button and wait for a few moments. After the phone reboots, your phone should be rooted.